# Gatling - extract token from response headers

Tags: gatling

I'm a newer in Gatling and I created a POST login request which returns the following response headers:

```html
HTTP/1.1 302 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ECA5F6FEA172B13BF5D445399C9C0962; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:20001/index;jsessionid=ECA5F6FEA172B13BF5D445399C9C0962
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 06 May 2021 16:01:20 GMT
```

I need to extract JSESSIONID value and use it in other requests.
I tried:

```
.check(regex("JSESSIONID=(.*?);").find.saveAs("token")))
```

however got an  error

```
> regex(JSESSIONID=(.*?);).findAll.exists, found nothing              1 (100.0%)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `headerRegex`

```
.check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie", """JSESSIONID=(.*?);"""").saveAs("token"))
```

Comment: Still get `Error headerRegex((Set-Cookie,JSESSIONID=(.*?);")).find.exists, found nothing`, however regular expression itself works well

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a redirect. I think the problem is that you have a redirect and the value is taken from the last "request". Try add `.disableFollowRedirect` to your request

Comment: Also yon can try 
`.exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("JSESSIONID").saveAs("token")))`

https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_helpers/#getting-a-cookie-value

Comment: `getCookieValue` works well even without `.disableFollowRedirect`. Thanks